# $\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) dx \rightarrow 0$ for $f \in L^p, g_n \in L^q$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Define:
$g_n(x)=n \chi_{[0,n^{-3}]}(x)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Show that, if $f \in L^2([0,1])$, then
$\int_0^1 f(x)g_n(x) dx \rightarrow 0$.

My Idea would be to use the Hölder inequality.
First, I have to show that $(g_n)_n \in L^2$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
So, $\int_0^1 |n \chi_{[0,n^{-3}(x)]}|^2 dx=\int_0^{n^{-3}} n^2 dx= 1/n$

By the Hölder inequality:
$|\int_0^1 f(x) n \chi_{[0,n^{-3}]}(x) dx|\leq ||f||_2 ||g_n||_2$.

Now, since $||g_n||_2= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $||f||_2 < \infty$ we get:
$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||f||_2 ||g_n||_2=0$.

I would like to know if my calculations are right. I do think that this is how it should work, but I am always a little bit worried if Hilbert spaces come up, but I don't use the inner product.
Some question on the side.

Do I need to use the Hölder inequality, or is there another way to show this? If this does not depend on the Hölder inequality, and thus does not need for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. does this hold for $f \in L^1$, $f \in L^3 ,... $.

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do use the inner product since $\langle f, g \rangle_{L^2} = \int f \text{ } \overline{g} \text{ } d \mu,$ which reduces to $\int f g d \mu$ when $g$ is real. As for the general case, you can use the general Hölder inequality $\Vert f g_n \Vert_1 \leq \Vert f \Vert_p \Vert g_n \Vert_q.$ To see when $\Vert g_n \Vert_q \to 0,$ we compute
$$\int_0^1 \vert g_n \vert^q d \mu = \int_0^{n^{-3}} n^q d \mu = n^{q-3},$$
so we obtain $\vert \int_0^1 f g_n d \mu \vert \leq n^\frac{q - 3}{q}\Vert f \Vert_p,$ which converges to $0$ whenever $q < 3.$ Thus the statement holds whenever $p > \frac{3}{2}.$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Adding to the first point, using the Hölder inequality as the OP does can be viewed as applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in the Hilbert space $L^{2}$.

Comment: Precisely my point, cheers for expanding on that! :)